# ExtJS bidirectional complex data binding Form

Tags: extjs4

give a JSON data like this

> { name: { firstname: 'First Name', lastname: 'Last Name' } }

I can model use model mapping

```
fields: [
  {Name: 'firstname', mapping: 'name.firstname'},
  {Name: 'lastname', mapping: 'name.lastname'}
]
```

It allow us to load the data into form like this

> First Name: [ First Name ]
>
> Last Name: [ Last Name ]

However when we submit the form Ext serialize the content as

```
{ "firstname": "New first name", "lastname": "New last name"}  
// instead of 
{ "name": { "firstname": "...", "lastname": "..."} }
```

Is there anyway I can tell Ext to serialize the object back to the nest form, regards.

P.S: my Edit.js taking from Ext MVC application guide http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure two properties in your json writer. You need to set `nameProperty: 'mapping'`, and `expandData: true`. For example, if you are configuring this writer in the proxy in your model, it would look like this:

```
proxy: {
    // other proxy config...
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        nameProperty: 'mapping',
        expandData: true
    }
}
```

`nameProperty` determines where the property name for each field comes from: either the `name` property or the `mapping` property. So, using your example, this will produce an object like this:

```
{ 'name.firstname': 'New first name', 'name.lastname': 'New last name' }
```

This is quite what you want yet, and that is where `expandData` comes in. This tells it to expand those dot-delimited properties in the example above, and create nested objects.

```
{ 'name': { 'firstname': 'New first name', 'lastname': 'New last name' } }
```

Docs:

- [nameProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-nameProperty)
- [expandData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-expandData)